# メッセージから文字を抜き出してjsonで保存したい

Tags: python

```
msg = "辞書登録:ドラえもん_クレヨンしんちゃん"
```

これで、

```
{
  "ドラえもん": "クレヨンしんちゃん"
}
```

つまり、メッセージの本文から「辞書登録」を抜いて「ドラえもん」と「クレヨンしんちゃん」だけをjsonで保存したいのですがどうしたらいいですか？

Answer (score 2):

正規表現で置換するのが簡単かと。
`^辞書登録:(.+)_(.+)$`を`{\n"$1":"$2"\n}`
に置換したら良いと思います。

具体的には、正規表現を扱う標準ライブラリの [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) を使って、例えば次のようにできます。

```
import re
msg = "辞書登録:ドラえもん_クレヨンしんちゃん"
pat = re.compile(r'^辞書登録:(.+)_(.+)$')
print(pat.sub( '{\n"\\1" : "\\2"\n}', msg ))
# {
# "ドラえもん":"クレヨンしんちゃん"
# }
```

Comment: `if msg.text == "辞書登録:(.+)_(.+)$":
       print ("$1")`

こんな感じでいいですか？

Answer (score 1):

`辞書登録:` が固定の文字列なら、以下のようにすればよさそうです。

```
import json

data = {}
key, value = msg[5:].split('_')
data[key] = value
s = json.dumps(data)
print(s)
```